# Not able to add the same product to the cart

Tags: php, jquery, html, session

I have created an add to cart code using session and jquery. It's almost done but I am getting two issues.

1) When I refresh the page, I am getting error

`Notice: Undefined index: quantity in C:\xampp\htdocs\add-to-cart\ajax_cart.php on line 5`

2) I am able to add the product to the cart but If I add the same product two times then I am getting the error.

```
 Notice: Undefined index: 250.00 in C:\xampp\htdocs\add-to-cart\ajax_cart.php on line 30
 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\add-to-cart\ajax_cart.php on line 31
```

There is some issue with else part (might be the price).

```
else{
    $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$product_price] = $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$product_price] + ($product_price*$quantity);
    $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$quantity] = $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$quantity]+$quantity;
    }
```

**AJAX function to call the ajax_cart.php**

```
function add_cart(p_id=""){
    var quantity = $(".quantity"+p_id).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"ajax_cart.php",
        data:{action:'add',p_id:p_id,quantity:quantity},
        success:function(result){
            $('.cart_data').html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

**Add to Cart**

```
$action = $_POST['action'];
 $p_id   = trim($_POST['p_id']);
 $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
if($action == 'add'){
     if(!empty($p_id)){
           $query = "SELECT product_id,product_title,product_price,product_image FROM product WHERE product_id=?";
            if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($query)) {
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $p_id);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($product_id, $product_title,$product_price, $product_image);
                $stmt->fetch();
              }

             $product = array(
                "p_id"=>$product_id,
                "title"=>$product_title,
                "price"=>$product_price*$quantity,
                "image"=>$product_image,
                "quantity"=>$quantity
             );
        if(isset($_SESSION['product_cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['product_cart']))
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($product_id,$_SESSION['product_cart']))
            {
                $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id] = $product;
            }
            else{
                $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$product_price] = $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$product_price] + ($product_price*$quantity);
                $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$quantity] = $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$quantity]+$quantity;
            }       
        }
        else{
          $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id] = $product;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Dont assign `$product_price` and `$quantity` as array keys, set them as the values. How tightly coupled is `$_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id][$quantity]` now? You should put `$product` in `$_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id]['product'] = $product` instead then have a qty field. You dont need price, you can calculate that when you output.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone, Appreciate your answer. Can you help me with more code? because If I remove the array the how it will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the else part as below

```
else{
            $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id]['price'] += ($product_price*$quantity);
            $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id]['quantity'] += $quantity;
        }
```

and add below code

`if(!isset($_POST['action']) || !isset($_POST['quantity'])) return;`

above the line

`$action = $_POST['action'];`

Comment: @fayis003, I tried your code but I am getting the same error.

Comment: check the updated code above.there was one more correction

Comment: Yes, This time it's working and Please help me with first one issue.

Comment: print the exact line of which your getting error please

Comment: add this to above all `if(!isset($_POST['quantity']) || !isset($_POST['quantity'])) return;`

Comment: You mean to say I have to use above code in the top after my database connection?

Comment: yes you can add `if(!isset($_POST['action']) || !isset($_POST['quantity'])) return;`  above the line `$action = $_POST['action'];`

Comment: Yes, It's also working. Please add this code to the answer.

Comment: I need some help. I have to display the add to cart code in the checkout page then what logic I have to use it?

Comment: sorry, but I didn't get what you meant? you can include the above code anywhere you wish and don't forget to put the `isset` condition or you will end up in error if the request doesn't contain the action or quantity

Comment: I mean, I am creating checkout page and what code I have to use it. Should I pass the session to the checkout page?

Comment: if you need an add to cart functionality in checkout page too obviously you need to include cart addition code in that too, otherwise, you just to use a code to get the added products from session like `$products = isset($_SESSION['products']) ? $_SESSION['products'] : [];`

Comment: Can you help me more?

Comment: how could I help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!array_key_exists($product_id,$_SESSION['product_cart']))
{
    $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id] = $product;
}
else{
    $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id]['price'] += ($product_price*$quantity);
    $_SESSION['product_cart'][$product_id]['quantity'] += $quantity;
}
```